Using GeoJSON timestamped Folium plugin for data in milliseconds
I have data from different points that a car pass by, and a need to put them in a map, but one by one using their UTC time. The data goes from one millisecond to another, and I need to reflect that.
The problem is that I have tried with the datetimes convertion and with GeoJSON timestamped from Folium, but the minimum period is PT1S and I need something like PT0.001S or something like that.
I have tried this idea but it doesn't work only shows all the cars together that appear in one second.
Some data that I have:
start_geojson1 = [{'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614925534909888, 43.10203250378655]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:3.8228061569467195 car_1',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.267000 index:0',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=218.0&g=112.0&b=214.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614968685776747, 43.10199635105799]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:3.755628040062408 car_2',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.270000 index:1',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=255.0&g=99.0&b=71.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614891111184642, 43.10244942928305]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:5.16605026190332 car_3',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.271000 index:2',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=0.0&g=128.0&b=128.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.61492451843729, 43.102037380768955]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.20118531187136 car_1',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.387000 index:3',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=218.0&g=112.0&b=214.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614970578353914, 43.10200140790472]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.248070150077562 car_2',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.388000 index:4',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=255.0&g=99.0&b=71.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614891549233812, 43.10245277741873]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:5.19298446504455 car_3',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.390000 index:5',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=0.0&g=128.0&b=128.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614928061166649, 43.10204264310815]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.0658772761462565 car_1',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.507000 index:6',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=218.0&g=112.0&b=214.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614973151404881, 43.10200792929416]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.413139751821108 car_2',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.511000 index:7',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=255.0&g=99.0&b=71.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614891213230031, 43.10245830955441]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.990936229239516 car_3',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.512000 index:8',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=0.0&g=128.0&b=128.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614927687956056, 43.10204600310815]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.198088924412573 car_1',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.627000 index:9',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=218.0&g=112.0&b=214.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614975323613487, 43.10201191881929]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.371417404392921 car_2',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.628000 index:10',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=255.0&g=99.0&b=71.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614889021862622, 43.10246148969008]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.434245241769539 car_3',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.631000 index:11',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=0.0&g=128.0&b=128.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614925897431769, 43.102051042158415]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.4653150248980396 car_1',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.747000 index:12',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=218.0&g=112.0&b=214.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614976442139994, 43.10201677800522]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.561479346344191 car_2',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.751000 index:13',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=255.0&g=99.0&b=71.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [-7.614887426965831, 43.10246730941873]},
  'properties': {'time': '2024-04-08 14:31:43',
   'style': {'color': '', 'weight': 1},
   'icon': 'marker',
   'tooltip': 'speed:4.498987677624135 car_3',
   'popup': '2024-06-26 14:31:43.754000 index:14',
   'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': 'https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../releases/preview/2016/png/iconmonstr-car-3.png&r=0.0&g=128.0&b=128.0',
    'iconSize': [15, 15]}}}]

The way that i do the folium map:
m=folium.Map(
            tiles = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
            attr = 'Esri',
            name = 'Esri Satellite',
            location = [43.10203250378655,-7.614925534909888], 
            zoom_start = 18, max_zoom=25, control_scale=True)
basemaps['Google Satellite'].add_to(m)
folium.plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(start_geojson1[0:15], 
        period="PT1S",
        date_options='HH:mm:ss',
        transition_time= 100,
        duration= "PT0S",
        add_last_point=True,
        time_slider_drag_update=True
    ).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl('topright', collapsed=True).add_to(m)
m

I need to represent every icon in every millisecond and that the timeslider control that to.

You are out of luck here. Folium TimestampedGeoJson plugin expects period in ISO8601 Duration format, but the lowest granularity for this format are seconds: https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001488-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm
